# How to draw a Drawable over a View

Tags: android, drawable

I have several Views in my Activity. I want to draw a Drawable over these views. 
The Drawable should be on top of the views (that means it hides the views below it.
The Drawable may appear over several views (that is I can't just draw it in one view).
How can this be done?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The FrameLayout allows you to have overlapping views. This is often used if you have some sort of background, with widgets over it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use a Dialog or view with Dialog Theme with your drawable as the background?